# Converting a row of string numbers to int

Tags: c#, string, split, integer

I have a txt with multiple rows, in the first row the first number *N* is how many rows there'll be after the third and the second number *M* is the amount of colums there will be. The second row contains *M* amount of numbers. The third one is the same as the second one just with a lower number.
The example looks like this:

```
6 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
8 4 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 5 7 6 6 6 6 5
6 6 6 5 5 5 5 6
8 6 8 7 7 7 7 6
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 1
```

So the *N* is 6 meaning there's six more rows after the 3rd one, *M* is 8 so there are 8 colums.
I've already split the first row and declared them to variables, and got the 9 and 5 declared. Now I have to split the remaining rows in the same array, so they are like this: "8" "4" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "7" "5" "7" "6" ect...
I've tried putting the rows in an array and then split them into another with a for cicle but it doesn't seem to work.
I've got this so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] frow = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int dn = int.Parse(frow[0]);
            int an = int.Parse(frow[1]);
            string[] rows = new string[an];
            int[] points = new int[an * dn];
            string[] mxp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            string[] mnp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int maxp = int.Parse(mxp[0]);
            int minp = int.Parse(mnp[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < dn; i++)
            {
                rows[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                points[i] = rows[i].Split(' ');
            }
        }
```

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: I would start by creating a function that takes a string and returns two things: 1) an array of numbers, and 2) and indication that the transformation was a success.  Do this using the `TryParseXxx` pattern. Then your code becomes: 1) Get the first line. 2) Using the dimensions, create a 2D array. 3) Then, in a loop, read each line, verifying the length and populating a row of the 2d array. I'd post an answer, but I don't have access to a compiler this week. This solution splits the work into two parts with different responsibilities, reading and parsing a line of numbers, and using those nums

Comment: What does *split the remaining rows in the same array* mean? It all ends up in one array? I think life would be easier to just `File.ReadAllText(path).Split().Select(int.Parse).Skip(2).ToArray()`

Comment: @Flydog57 *I don't have access to a compiler this week* - https://dotnetfiddle.net/ or just write it anyway; coder of your calibre doesn't need a compiler ;)

Comment: But your example data is an 8x8 not a 6x8 array. It's also unclear how you'd like to separate each row or column because your example split row isn't present in the data set EDIT: Actually, seems like your example rows are blending together. Caius Jard's method should work.

Comment: The reason for the 8x8 is because of this: _"The second row contains M amount of numbers. The third one is the same as the second one just with a lower number"_.  I have no clue what that means.  Is the code expected to just ignore the second and third lines of numbers?  @CaiusJard: I don't know about you, but my coding style requires someone or something to review what I type - I can live without a code review on something this simple, but getting code right without a compiler is tough.

Comment: Oh, there's an army of angry downvoting nitpickers out there waiting to review any code posted :D. I'm happy to fix up any typos in it before they look at it. What I wanna know is, what if the file is like `2 2↵9 9↵5 5↵2 2 3↵4` are we supposed to just return "2 2 4" ? "2 2 3 4" ? What if the file isn't the shape described on the first line? What if it's jagged over/under?

Comment: @gergö: you asked this a year and a half ago. You got two answers. Were either of them of any use. Neither answer has had an upvote and neither has been accepted. The way this site works relies on question askers to acknowledge the usefulness of answers with upvites or an "accepted" check

Answer (score 0):

Why do something in one line of code when you can do it in a whole page?

This is what I was talking about in the comments.  First I create a function that, when given a line of text, returns an array of integers:

```
public static bool TryGetLineOfNumbers (string line, out int[] numbers){
    numbers = null;     //out parameters must always be set, cover the failure case
    var individualStrings = line.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    numbers = new int[individualStrings.Length];
    // convert the strings into numbers, failing on a conversion error
    for(var i = 0; i< individualStrings.Length; ++i){
        if (!int.TryParse(individualStrings[i], out numbers[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm way too lazy to type nine lines of numbers into a console, so I just created a hard-coded array of strings in my main function:

```
var testNumbers = new string[]{
    "6 8",
    "9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9",
    "5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5",
    "8 4 6 6 6 6 6 6",
    "7 5 7 6 6 6 6 5",
    "6 6 6 5 5 5 5 6",
    "8 6 8 7 7 7 7 6",
    "8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6",
    "8 6 6 6 6 6 6 1",
};
```

My intention was to have a function that read the console and returned an `IEnumerable<string>` (so that I could use the hard-coded array or the function in my testing), but I couldn't get DotNet Fiddle to handle `yield return` properly (it also didn't like interpolated strings).  That function (which didn't work) looked like:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetStringsFromConsole(){
    var str = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)){
        yield return str;
    }
}
```

So, now my `Main` routine looks like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var testNumbers = new string[]{
        "6 8",
        "9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9",
        "5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5",
        "8 4 6 6 6 6 6 6",
        "7 5 7 6 6 6 6 5",
        "6 6 6 5 5 5 5 6",
        "8 6 8 7 7 7 7 6",
        "8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6",
        "8 6 6 6 6 6 6 1",
    };
    //need to initialize these to keep the compiler happy
    var lineNumber = 0;
    int [,] numbers = null;
    int[] dimensions = null;
    
    foreach (var line in testNumbers)
    {
        ++lineNumber;   //i.e., it starts with one
        if (lineNumber == 1) {
            var firstLineValid = TryGetLineOfNumbers(line, out dimensions);
            if (!firstLineValid || dimensions.Length != 2) {
                throw new Exception ("The first line of text must have exactly two numbers");
            }
            numbers = new int[dimensions[0], dimensions[1]];
        } else if (lineNumber < 4){
            int[] ignoredNumbers;
            var line23Valid = TryGetLineOfNumbers(line, out ignoredNumbers);
            if (!line23Valid || ignoredNumbers.Length != dimensions[1]){
                throw new Exception ("The second or third line is in the incorrect format");
            }
        } else {
            int[] oneLine;
            var normalLineValid = TryGetLineOfNumbers(line, out oneLine);
            if (!normalLineValid || oneLine.Length != dimensions[1]){
                throw new Exception ("Line " + lineNumber.ToString() + " is incorrectly formatted");
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < dimensions[1]; ++i){
                numbers[lineNumber-4, i] = oneLine[i];
            }                   
        }
    }
    if (lineNumber != dimensions[0] + 3){
        throw new Exception("Not enough inputted data");
    }
    
    //ok, got all the numbers, let's see them on the console:
    for(var i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; ++i){
        for(var j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; ++j){
            Console.Write(numbers[i,j].ToString() + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Yeah, it's a lot of code, but it's pretty self-explanatory.  It also pays attention and validates the inputs.  It's lightly tested

Reading the code over, it's probably worth refactoring the format and length test code (repeated three times) into a separate function, but that would be for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just a general example of how you can split strings. Copy and paste your data to a file, and change the filePath string to match the path of the file. Run below. I suggest setting a breakpoint at the Console.ReadKey() and looking at each of the variables after they've been assigned to, to see what each function does:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace HelpingStackOverflow
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

        string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\data.txt";
        string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        string[] allLines = fileContents.Split('\n');
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(allLines[0].Split(" ")[0]);
        int m = Convert.ToInt32(allLines[0].Split(" ")[1]);
        string secondRow = allLines[1].Trim('\r');
        string thirdRow = allLines[2].Trim('\r');
        string[] remainingLines = allLines.Skip(3).ToArray();

        //so now you have different arrays
        //if you want to break a line into an additional array you can do so
        //and do whatever you want with the parts like this:

        List<string[]> allParts = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (string line in remainingLines)
        {
            var parts = line.Trim('\r').Split(" ");
            allParts.Add(parts);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}